# Theos Tweak compilation errors

Tags: ios, arm64

While attempting to build a Theos tweak, even a templated one created by Theos, I will encounter the following error

```
bash: line 1:  4665 Done                    swift --version
      4667 Broken pipe: 13         | head -1
      4669 Killed: 9               | cut -d'v' -f2
      4670 Killed: 9               | cut -d' ' -f2
      4672 Killed: 9               | cut -d'-' -f1

....

bash: -c: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [/var/root/theos/makefiles/package.mk:80: internal-install-check] Error 1
```

I did some searching online but could not find a solution. If anyone knows about this, appreciate if you can provide some suggestions.

Comment: Not RE. Try the tool chain support options from wherever you got it.